# Adding an array of artists to 1 festival doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add an array of different types of artists to a festival which will the be displayed on the page. Festivals have their own model, and so do artists.

This is the artist model:

```
export class Artist{
    // public _id: string;
    public name: string;
    public genre: string;

    constructor(name: string, genre: string){
        // this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

The festival model:

```
import { Artist } from './artist.model';

export class Festival{
    // public _id: string;
    public name: string;
    public genre: string;
    public description: string;
    public location: string;
    public imageUrl: string;
    public price: number;
    public artist: Artist;

    constructor( name: string, genre: string, description: string, location: string, imageurl: string, price: number, artist: Artist)
    {
        // this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
        this.imageUrl = imageurl;
        this.price = price;
        this.artist = artist;
    }
}
```

The festival service that creates these new instances of festival for now:

```
import { Festival } from 'src/app/models/festival.model';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Artist } from 'src/app/models/artist.model';

export class FestivalService{
    festivalSelected = new EventEmitter<Festival>();

    private festivals: Festival[] = [
        new Festival('DGTL', 'Techno', 'Test description', 'Amsterdam', 'https://festivalfans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dgtl-2017.jpg', 45, [] ),
        new Festival('RR', 'Techno', 'Party', 'Rotterdam', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAeFBMVEUAAAD////6+vodHR3', 45)
      ];

      getFestivals() {
          return this.festivals.slice();
      }
      addFestivalsToFavorites(festival: Festival[]){

      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe problem is in the festival model... property artist is not an array.

```
import { Artist } from './artist.model';

export class Festival{
    // public _id: string;
    public name: string;
    public genre: string;
    public description: string;
    public location: string;
    public imageUrl: string;
    public price: number;
    public artists: Artist[];

    constructor( name: string, genre: string, description: string, location: string, imageurl: string, price: number, artists: Artist[])
    {
        // this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
        this.imageUrl = imageurl;
        this.price = price;
        this.artists = artists;
    }
}
```

You can also use this shorter constructor for your class:

```
import { Artist } from './artist.model';

export class Festival{

    constructor( name: string, genre: string, description: string, location: string, imageurl: string, price: number, artists: Artist[])
    {
        // public _id = _id;
        public name = name;
        public genre = genre;
        public description = description;
        public location = location;
        public imageUrl = imageurl;
        public price = price;
        public artists = artists;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I add such an artist to a festival in the festival.service.ts? So in the  new Festival('DGTL', 'Techno', 'Wie dit leest is een aapje', 'Amsterdam', 'https://festivalfans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dgtl-2017.jpg', 45, Artist) string

Comment: new Festival('DGTL', 'Techno', 'Wie dit leest is een aapje', 'Amsterdam', 'festivalfans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dgtl-2017.jpg', 45, [Artist])

try adding [Artist]

Comment: Adding [Artist] seems to solve the error, but doesn't fill the variable with data. I would like to add a artist with the following parameters of the artist model. That means a name and a genre.